# How to define runtime source_type inside "has many through" polymorphic association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model-associations

Is there any way to define `source_type` runtime inside rails `has_many` `through` `polymorphic` association.

Below code should give you brief idea .. but its not working.. any suggestions ??

```
class A < ...
  has_many :message_messagables, :foreign_key => :message_id

  has_many :messagables, :through => :message_messagables, :source => :messagable, :source_type => lambda { |a| a.custom_type }

 def custom_type
   raise "needs to be defined inside subclass"
 end

end


class MessageMessagable < ... 
 belongs_to :messagable, :polymorphic => true #[C, D]
 belongs_to :message
end

class B < A

 def custom_type
   "C"
 end
end

class E < A
 def custom_type
   "D"
 end

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the same problem. I resolved it by listing all avaiable source types and added a dispatch method.

```ruby
class A < ...
  has_many :message_messagables, :foreign_key => :message_id

  # list all source types as association
  %w(email file).each do |source_type|
    has_many source_type.pluralize.to_sym, :through => :message_messagables, :source => :messagable, :source_type => source_type
  end

  # dispatch methodk
  def messagables
    public_send custom_type.pluralize.to_sym
  end
end
```